# How to get the Previous & next row based on condition

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get the statement on fetching the previous and next rows of a selected row.

```
Declare @OderDetail table
(
    Id int primary key,
    OrderId int,
    ItemId int,
    OrderDate DateTime2,
    Lookup varchar(15)
)

INSERT INTO @OderDetail 
VALUES  
(1, 10, 1, '2018-06-11', 'A'), 
(2, 10, 2, '2018-06-11', 'BE'), --this
(3, 2, 1, '2018-06-04', 'DR'),
(4, 2, 2, '2018-06-04', 'D'),  --this
(5, 3, 2, '2018-06-14', 'DD'), --this
(6, 4, 2, '2018-06-14', 'R');


DECLARE 
    @ItemId int = 2,
    @orderid int = 10
```

Required output:

[image]

Input for the procedure is  order id =10 and item id =2  and i need to check item-2 is in the any other order i.e only previous and next item of  matched record/order as per order date

Comment: What is your server version?

Comment: SQL server 2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what your after?  (Updated to reflect edit [OrderDate] to question)

```
Declare @OderDetail table
(
    Id int primary key,
    OrderId int,
    ItemId int,
    OrderDate DateTime2,
    Lookup varchar(15)
)

INSERT INTO @OderDetail 
VALUES  
(1, 10, 1, '2018-06-11', 'A'), 
(2, 10, 2, '2018-06-11', 'BE'), --this
(3, 2, 1, '2018-06-04', 'DR'),
(4, 2, 2, '2018-06-04', 'D'),  --this
(5, 3, 2, '2018-06-14', 'DD'), --this
(6, 4, 2, '2018-06-14', 'R');

declare @ItemId  int=2 , @orderid int = 10;
```

Query

```
With cte As
(
Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY OrderDate) AS RecN,
* 
From @OderDetail Where ItemId=@ItemId
) 
Select Id, OrderId, ItemId, [Lookup] From cte Where 
RecN Between ((Select Top 1 RecN From cte Where OrderId = @orderid) -1) And
((Select Top 1 RecN From cte Where  OrderId = @orderid) +1) 
Order by id
```

Result:

```
Id  OrderId ItemId  Lookup
2   10      2       BE
4   2       2       D
5   3       2       DD
```

Comment: i have updated the question..please update ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY OrderDate) AS RecN,

Comment: I have updated this as per the edit to the question for OrderDate column and @Orderid variable.

Answer (score 1):

Update to given this data set: I see where you are going with this.  Note that in SOME cases there IS no row before the given one - so it only returns 2 not 3.  Here I updated the CTE version.  Un-comment the OTHER row to see 3 not 2 as there is then one before the selected row with that Itemid.

Added a variable to demonstrate how this is better allowing you to get 1 before and after or 2 before/after if you change that number (i.e. pass a parameter) - and if less rows, or none are before or after it gets as many as it can within that constraint.

Data setup for all versions:

```
Declare @OderDetail table
(
    Id int primary key,
    OrderId int,
    ItemId int,
    OrderDate DateTime2,
    Lookup varchar(15)
)

INSERT INTO @OderDetail 
VALUES  
(1, 10, 1, '2018-06-11', 'A'), 
(2, 10, 2, '2018-06-11', 'BE'), --this
(3, 2, 1, '2018-06-04', 'DR'),
(4, 2, 2, '2018-06-04', 'D'),  --this
(5, 3, 2, '2018-06-14', 'DD'), --this
(9, 4, 2, '2018-06-14', 'DD'), 
(6, 4, 2, '2018-06-14', 'R'),
--(10, 10, 2, '2018-06-02', 'BE'), -- un-comment to see one before
(23, 4, 2, '2018-06-14', 'R');

DECLARE 
    @ItemId int = 2,
    @orderid int = 2;
```

CTE updated version:

```
DECLARE @rowsBeforeAndAfter INT = 1;
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        Id,
        OrderId,
        ItemId,
        OrderDate,
        [Lookup],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderDate,Id) AS RowNumber
    FROM @OderDetail
    WHERE 
        ItemId = @itemId -- all matches of this
),
myrow AS (
    SELECT TOP 1
        Id,
        OrderId,
        ItemId,
        OrderDate,
        [Lookup],
        RowNumber
    FROM cte
    WHERE 
        ItemId = @itemId 
        AND OrderId = @orderid
)
SELECT 
    cte.Id,
    cte.OrderId,
    cte.ItemId,
    cte.OrderDate,
    cte.[Lookup],
    cte.RowNumber
FROM ctE
INNER JOIN myrow
    ON ABS(cte.RowNumber - myrow.RowNumber) <= @rowsBeforeAndAfter
ORDER BY OrderDate, OrderId;
```

You probably want the CTE method (**See an original at the end of this**) however:

Just to point out, this gets the proper results but is probably not what you are striving for since it is dependent on the row order and the item id not the actual row with those two values:

```
SELECT TOP  3
    a.Id,
    a.OrderId,
    a.ItemId,
    a.Lookup
FROM @OderDetail AS a
WHERE 
     a.ItemId = @ItemId
```

To fix that, you can use an `ORDER BY` and `TOP 1` with a `UNION`, kind of ugly. (UPDATED with date sort and != on the id.)

```
SELECT 
        u.Id,
        u.OrderId,
        u.OrderDate,
        u.ItemId,
        u.Lookup
FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.Id,
        a.OrderId,
        a.OrderDate,
        a.ItemId,
        a.Lookup
    FROM @OderDetail AS a
    WHERE 
         a.ItemId = @ItemId
         AND a.OrderId = @orderid
    UNION 
    SELECT top 1
        b.Id,
        b.OrderId,
        b.OrderDate,
        b.ItemId,
        b.Lookup
    FROM @OderDetail AS b
    WHERE 
         b.ItemId = @ItemId
         AND b.OrderId != @orderid
    ORDER BY b.OrderDate desc, b.OrderId
    UNION 
    SELECT top 1
        b.Id,
        b.OrderId,
        b.OrderDate,
        b.ItemId,
        b.Lookup
    FROM @OderDetail AS b
    WHERE 
         b.ItemId = @ItemId
        AND b.OrderId != @orderid
    ORDER BY b.OrderDate asc, b.OrderId 
) AS u
ORDER BY u.OrderDate asc, u.OrderId
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... actually order date named additional column exist which i mentioned here... rows order must be based on orderdate not order id

Comment: I see no order date mentioned anywhere until now, would have been good to have that in your original question data and notes.  Let's see if we can accommodate that change.

Comment: I added an update including a CTE option - which is probably the best, the form differs slightly from other answers a bit.

Comment: Thanks..but i have updated the question..Ur Cte as well  sub query not working for order id 10 and item -id -2 for given data in the upated question. (Order id is not always sequence) any suggestion

Comment: For those numbers I see:
`Id OrderId ItemId OrderDate Lookup RowNumber
2 10 2 2018-06-11 00:00:00.0000000 BE 3
5 3 2 2018-06-14 00:00:00.0000000 DD 4
6 4 2 2018-06-14 00:00:00.0000000 R 5`

Answer (score 1):

Another possible approach is to use `LAG()` and `LEAD()` functions, that return  data from a previous and subsequent row form the same resul tset.

```
-- Table
DECLARE @OrderDetail TABLE (
    Id int primary key,
    OrderId int,
    ItemId int,
    OrderDate DateTime2,
    Lookup varchar(15)
)
INSERT INTO @OrderDetail 
VALUES  
   (1, 10, 1, '2018-06-11', 'A'), 
   (2, 10, 2, '2018-06-11', 'BE'), --this
   (3, 2, 1, '2018-06-04', 'DR'),
   (4, 2, 2, '2018-06-04', 'D'),  --this
   (5, 3, 2, '2018-06-14', 'DD'), --this
   (6, 4, 2, '2018-06-14', 'R');

-- Item and order
DECLARE 
    @ItemId int = 2,
    @orderid int = 10

-- Statement    
-- Get previois and next ID for every order, grouped by ItemId, ordered by OrderDate
;WITH cte AS (
   SELECT
      Id,
      LAG(Id, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemId ORDER BY OrderDate) previousId,
      LEAD(Id, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemId ORDER BY OrderDate) nextId,
      ItemId,
      OrderId,
      Lookup
   FROM @OrderDetail   
)
-- Select current, previous and next order
SELECT od.*
FROM cte
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM @OrderDetail WHERE Id = cte.Id) od
WHERE (cte.OrderId = @orderId) AND (cte.ItemId = @ItemId)
UNION ALL
SELECT od.*
FROM cte
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM @OrderDetail WHERE Id = cte.previousId) od
WHERE (cte.OrderId = @orderId) AND (cte.ItemId = @ItemId)
UNION ALL
SELECT od.*
FROM cte
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM @OrderDetail WHERE Id = cte.nextId) od
WHERE (cte.OrderId = @orderId) AND (cte.ItemId = @ItemId)
```

Output:

```
Id  OrderId ItemId  OrderDate           Lookup
2   10      2       11/06/2018 00:00:00 BE
4   2       2       04/06/2018 00:00:00 D
5   3       2       14/06/2018 00:00:00 DD
```

Comment: I do not believe this works with gaps in the ID column as written

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I think it works even with gaps in Id column.

Comment: With the data in the question (was updated) 
`Id OrderId ItemId OrderDate Lookup
2 10 2 2018-06-11 00:00:00.0000000 BE
10 10 2 2018-06-02 00:00:00.0000000 BE
4 2 2 2018-06-04 00:00:00.0000000 D
4 2 2 2018-06-04 00:00:00.0000000 D
23 4 2 2018-06-14 00:00:00.0000000 R` if you add a gap or two

Comment: Thanks..this code will work..but  as per my thought @level3looper will be best solution  for original question (before update)

Answer (score 0):

I think its simple, you can check with min(Id) and Max(id) with left outer join or outer apply

like

```
Declare @ItemID int = 2
Select * From @OderDetail A
Outer Apply (
    Select MIN(A2.Id) minID, MAX(A2.Id) maxID From @OderDetail A2
    Where A2.ItemId =@ItemID
) I05
Outer Apply(
    Select * From @OderDetail Where Id=minID-1
    Union All
    Select * From @OderDetail Where Id=maxID+1
    ) I052
Where A.ItemId =@ItemID Order By A.Id
```

Let me know if this helps you or you face any problem with it...

Regards,

Comment: thanks but it return 4 rows but actually 3 rows.. i need to find ordet id=1 and item id=1

Comment: ohhh I missed orderId parameter :) you just need to add that parameter...